# Fazer input de Imagens com Dropzone em requisição AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dropzonejs

estou com um problema no meu código referente ao tentar realizar um input de imagens via AJAX.

O script PHP está ok, pois o mesmo código é usado em outras operações, mas acredito que tenha algo errado no meu código javascript.

HTML

```html
<form>
    <div class="form-group" id="selecionarDoc">
        <label for="file">Selecione a imagem</label>
        <form action="https://endpoint/apis.php" class="dropzone dz-clickable" id="MyDropzone">
            <div class="dz-default dz-message">
                <span><i class="material-icons icon-2x text-primary mb-4">cloud_upload</i></span>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-lg rounded border-0 z-3" id="btnSubmit">Cadastrar</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```js
$(document).on('click', '#btnSubmit', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://endpoint/apis.php",
        action: 'cadastraFotos',
        success: function(data) {
            Alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Parece que o código nem chega no servidor, pois não me retornada nada no console.log

Comment: se o codigo em php já é utilizado em outras aplicações, chegou a comparar as chamadas? é um post ou get?

Comment: Eu já fiz o teste da forma GET e POST... e abaixo da url do ajax, também passei o método, mas não deu certo.

Comment: implementa um handler de erro no seu ajax pra ver o que está acontecendo, assim: `error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {  .... inspecioana os parametros }`